# pygeoprocessing - raster calculator

Tags: python-2.7, pygeoprocessing

I am new in pygeoprocessing and I am trying to do a really simple raster calculation. I would like to calculate element-wise average over several rasters.

I first though pygeoprocessing could handle it the same way R's Raster package does it (stack of rasters and then apply a function) but couldn't find a way to do it so I am trying with the raster calculator.

I have 2 ratsers R1.tif and R2.tif and would like to calculate the raster Rmean.tif with same extent as R1 and R2. Here is what I tried:

```
import pygeoprocessing.geoprocessing as geop

listraster_uri = [('R1.tif',1),('R2.tif',1)]
rasterout_uri='R.tif'

def avg(r1,r2):
   result_avg=(r1+r2)/2.
   return result_avg

geop.raster_calculator(base_raster_path_band_list=listraster_uri,
            local_op=avg, 
            target_raster_path=rasterout_uri,
            datatype_target(np.float32,1),
            nodata_target=-1,
            calc_raster_stats=False)
```

but I get this error :

TypeError: in method 'Driver_Create', argument 6 of type 'GDALDataType'

because I don't know how to specify the "desired GDAL output type of the target raster"m beside the fact that I don't know if I am doing the right thing here...

Is there a way to stack the ratsers and apply a numpy function like pandas does over dataframes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a numpy `dtype` not a GDAL data type constant as the `datatype_target`

Try `gdal.GDT_Float32` instead:

```
geop.raster_calculator(base_raster_path_band_list=listraster_uri,
            local_op=avg, 
            target_raster_path=rasterout_uri,
            datatype_target=gdal.GDT_Float32,
            nodata_target=-1,
            calc_raster_stats=False)
```